# How to see upper comment in method tooltip ES6/JS

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, when I mouse over a used method, it shows it's definition in a tooltip.

[image: tooltip example]

Is there any way in VSCode to see in this tooltip, the comment that is written in the line above the method definition?

Comment: What does the comment look like? VS Code supports JSDoc style comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the comment is written with double slashes (`//`) then it won't show. It has to be in the JSDoc syntax (`/** */`)

Answer (score 1):

**No**, but you can open a suggestion on their [official github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode)